# ruby on rails scaffold form with :date field, converting it to string

Tags: date, ruby-on-rails-4, tostring, object-to-string

I have a scaffold form with a field '`date:date`' and I want to convert it to a string after the form has been submitted to use it in creating another model, what is the best way of doing this? [This](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) has some info but none of the methods work, maybe the scaffold date object is different from a regular Date object?. I know I can rescaffold it as a string but I need to convert it.

`review_params[:date].to_s(:db)` returns a NoMethodError

Comment: I'm not sure what you want and if it is necessary, but you should call params[:date] instead of review_params[:date].

Comment: well my scaffold form is called Reviews and my function for the parameters is called review_params, so what would that accomplish?

Comment: The method you are referring to contains your strong parameters, which determine what attributes are whitelisted. However, your URL parameters  are stored in the params hash. If you want to see what gets submitted in your form you can check params[:date] for example. I would use debugger or pry to check what your parameters contain.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, if anyone else has same issue with extracting date from 1 form and using it to create another model.

```
date_string = "#{review_params['date(1i)']}-#{review_params['date(2i)']}-#{review_params['date(3i)']}"
@concert = Concert.find_or_create_by!(artist: review_params[:artist], venue: review_params[:venue], date: date_string)
```